# Equivalent condition for an open set in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm reviewing for a first-year exam in introductory topology.  I've run across this question:

Let $X$ be a metric space.  Prove that a subset $U$ of $X$ is open iff for every $z\in U$ and every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\omega}$ that converges to $z$, there exists an $N\in\omega$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $x_n\in U$.

The forward direction is easy.  The converse has always, \textit{always} given me trouble, for some reason.  I can't figure out how to construct an open ball completely contained in $U$ to show that the interior of $U$ is all of $U$.  I would like to make a sequence that encompasses all of the points in such an open ball, but I can only capture finite or countable subsets.  This should be super basic, but can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Also, apologies if this is a duplicate.  I couldn't figure out how to parse the question for Google.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried proof by contradiction? Suppose $U$ is not open...

Comment: In fact,open sets in a metric space are a reunion of open balls (in the sense of metric space) so your intuition is right but it's harder to construct those balls than to show that if it wasnt open,then $z$ would be on its complement.

Answer (score 2):

If $U$ is not open then it must contain an element $z$ that does not belong to the interior of $U$.

So for $n=1,2,\dots$ the open ball having $z$ as center and $\frac1n$ as radius has a nonempty intersection with $U^c$.

Choose $x_n$ as an element of that intersection. Then $x_n\to z\in U$ while $x_n\notin U$ for each $n$.

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I used immediately after I saw "have you tried contradiction?"

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is not open, then $U^c$ is not closed and hence not sequentially closed (use that $X$ is metric space), so there is a sequence of elements $x_n \to x \in X$ with $x_n \in U^c$ but $x \in U$.